# PreSaveAction and CAMLQuery

Tags: web-services, caml-query, spservices

I'm cross posting this from [Stump the Panel](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/STP/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3217) for some more visibility from a wider developer base.

I'm trying to create a script I'll eventually adapt into a PreSaveAction, but I'm running into a stumbling block with my CAMLQuery.  When I comment out the CAMLQuery, I return results back from the GetListItems call.  When I apply my CAMLQuery I tested in U2U, nothing happens.  Any pointers as to what my issue is?

```
var queryStringVals = $().SPServices.SPGetQueryString();
var cID = queryStringVals["c"];
//var cid = cID + ";#" + cID
var email = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "EMail",debug: false});
var ID = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "ID",debug: false});
//var string = ID + ";#" + email
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Current Registrations",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='CourseID' /><Value Type='Lookup'>"+ cID +"</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeEmail' /><Value Type='User'>"+ email +"</Value></Eq></And><Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        //iC = $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=rs:data]").attr("ItemCount");
   alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
     }
   });
```

Comment: dont know about SPServices, but for "normal" SPQuery, you must not include the `<Query>...</Query>` tag around the where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blast, typo in my CAMLQuery, that's why.  I didn't close the `<Where>` element properly:

```
 CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='CourseID' /><Value Type='Lookup'>"+ cID +"</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeEmail' /><Value Type='User'>"+ email +"</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query>",
```